# Only one record visible in my listview with custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I try to create a custom array adapter so I can make custom ListViews for my app.
The adapter I made:

```
package aaeu.app.presentationlayer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import aaeu.app.R;

public class AlertOverviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public AlertOverviewAdapter(Context context, String[] resource) {
        super(context,R.layout.test ,resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Do something with the icon....
        String s = values[position];
        if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
                || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {
            //set Ok icon
        } else {
            //set Not ok icon
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I try to load the adapter in my list view in this way:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new AlertOverviewAdapter(this, values);
lv_alert_overview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

my values:

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
```

When I run the app, only "Android" is shown in my list and I can't get it done that all the strings are visible in the listview. When I get this done I can modify the layout how I want.

I think the problem is something with the `int position` but I don't know what - can someone help me please?

Comment: post your layout files too

Comment: Ok... i struggled 2 hours with this... after this post i found the solution. By one weird reason i found out that a listview should not be in a scrolview? This fixed my problem!

Comment: @Mischra i found the solution already,  Thanks anyway! didn't know that a listview should not be in a scrolview....

Comment: listview should always be match parent height otherwise it only takes height of single row item. I also faced this problem few weeks ago and found this

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks!

Comment: ListView already has its own ScrollView, that is why you can't add a ListView in a ScrollView.